# How to reuse code when multiple inheritance is not an option?

Tags: c#, inheritance, oop, multiple-inheritance, reusability

I would like to make use of few methods from couple of my old tested classes into my new class that I am building. Unfortunately, C# does not support multiple inheritance. How do I reuse code from these old classes? Do I just create them as member objects? or Do I have any other options?

Comment: **FORTUNATELY** C# doesn't support multiple inheritance!

Comment: You shouldn't use inheritance for code reuse in *any* language, whether or not MI is supported.

Comment: @jalf: why not? inheritance is a powerful feature.

My controversial opinion is: would it be nice if C# DID support Multiple Inheritance?

Comment: @marc_s a nice example for a programming language that allows code sharing without inheritance is Swift. It allows you to define two classes with protocols (interfaces) and write a “protocol extension” - an extenstion that defines implementation for an interface, and who ever add that interface to a class will get the implementation for free ;)

Comment: @jalf see my comment (I’m not allowed to tag two users in one comment, sorry)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Generally, using composition instead of inheritance is the way forward, yes. If you could give a concrete example of the kind of thing you mean, that would make it easier to help find the appropriate approach though: it's not always the same.

Answer (score 5):

Using them as member objects should be a good idea. Then you can also expose only the methods of interest, and adapt them if necessary.

Comment: This is called the delegation pattern, though with delegates in .NET that might sound a little confusing.

Answer (score 4):

You can recreate then as extension methods when they work on the same type.

```
public static void MyMethod( this MyType target ){}


MyType.MyMethod()
```

as noted below, if you have a class which derives from MyType or more common implements the interface the extension method works on, the extension works for those.

```
public class MyDerived : MyType{}

MyDerived.MyMethod()
```

Comment: How would this help you to reuse code? You still have to define the extension method for your new class?

Comment: But they may be defined for generic types or for a more general interface, allowing the same extension method to be reused across a large number of classes.

Answer (score 2):

Technically, C# implements multiple *interface* inheritence, but not multiple 
*implementation* inheritence.

The problem with multiple implementation inheritence is that it leads to 
situations like [the diamond problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_problem).

You can simulate multiple implementation inheritence using multiple interface 
inheritence and composition, which is close to what you described as creating 
the objects that you want to re-use "as member objects".  What you don't want 
to do, however is expose unnecessary behaviour from your wrapped type.

Following is a class diagram showing the basic principle of multiple
inheritence through composition:

[Multiple Inheritance http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/cb219cefba.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/cb219cefba.jpg)

The drawback of this is that any changes to the interface IBreeper will require
corresponding changes to Breeper, and vice versa.

Taking a step back though - you need to carefully look at the reasons for
composing the old classes.  Is it to:

1. Enhance or step up existing behaviour.  You should then consider the [Proxy Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern);
2. Create a "one stop shop" for all of your behaviour.  You should really only be doing this if your **SuperFuddler** is *cohesive* (that is, all exposed behaviour is aligned), otherwise you'll be moving into a [God Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object) situation which isn't conducive to being maintainable;
3. Present an interface that is more consistent with a mode of use required by a certain class of clients of your SuperFuddler.  In this case, you should consider the [Adapter Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern).

Answer (score 0):

You can fake it pretty easily like this:

```
public interface IFoo {
    void DoFoo();
}

public class Foo : IFoo {
    public void DoFoo() { Console.Write("Foo"); }
}

public class Bar {
    public void DoBar() { Console.Write("Bar"); }
}

public class FooBar : IFoo, Bar {
    private IFoo baseFoo = new Foo();
    public void DoFoo() { baseFoo.DoFoo(); }
}

//...

FooBar fooBar = new FooBar();

fooBar.DoFoo();
fooBar.DoBar();
```